# How to compose a builder in a StreamBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I was trying to use the stream builder in flutter but I am getting these errors I do not seem to understand

```
The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>)'.

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
```

below is the small code for it

```
   builder: (BuildContext context , AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                    List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                    for(var message in messages){
                      final messageText = message.data()['text'];
                      final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
                      final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                      messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                    }
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        messageWidgets,
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                },
```

Please do help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of the error is because of wrong type assigned to Snapshot. And second line error is because you didn't returned anything from the builder body.

Use the StreamBuilder like this,

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(
   stream: your_stream,
   builder: (_, snapshot){
     if(condition){
       return AnyWidget();
     }
     return Something();
   }
)
```